# Spring injecting an initiallized mock via constructor

Tags: java, spring, junit, dependency-injection, mockito

I have a singleton class (so private constructor) which needs to use a Spring Data repository during initialization. I have one injected as a constructor argument. Roughly:

```
@Controller
public class MyClass {
    @Autowired
    private MyClass(MyRepository repo) {
        repo.findAll();
    }
}
```

I want to unit test my class, so I need to have a mock repository initialized with mock values and then passed into my class before my class is initialized. How do I write my Mockito mocks in my JUnit test to make this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Spring; this is an advantage of constructor injection. Just use `MyRepository mockRepo = mock(MyRepository.class)` and `new MyClass(mockRepo)`.

(Your constructor should be public, by the way. You seem to be making the common mistake of confusing different senses of "singleton"; in the case of DI it simply means that *the container* only makes a single instance and shares it. Finally, if you only have one constructor you don't need `@Autowired`.)

Comment: When used with real data, my class will take a bit of time to initialize and will use a non-trivial amount of memory, so I want to explicitly insure that there will only ever be one instance of my class.

Comment: @KonstantinTarashchanskiy This is a substantial code smell, and all the more reason to clean up your structure; for example, in a test, you should be able to return a handful of generated items (and also zero items!) from `findAll` to comprehensively test behavior.

Comment: I agree with  chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic - make the constructor in the class public, and set the bean scope in Spring to be singleton. That would make this trivial to test, and still maintain one instance per Spring context, which quite often means one instance per JVM.

If you absolutely can't do that for some reason, remove the access modifier completely (use default / package access) and annotate the constructor with @VisibleForTesting. Your test still remains trivial, and no classes outside the package containing the controller would be able to call the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Unit test should be independent. It means, we are not using real data from database even call any service from our test file.

Assuming you are using JUni5 and have `findAllStudents()` in your controller. So your test file approximately like this

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class MyClassTest {

    @Mock
    private MyRepository repo;
    
    @InjectMocks
    private MyClass controller;

    @BeforeAll
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testDataIsExist() {
        List<String> expectednames = new ArrayList();
        expectedNames.add("Foo");
        expectedNames.add("Bar");

        Mockito.when(myRepo.findAll()).thenReturn(expectedNames);

        List<String> result = controller.findAllStudents();
        Assertions.assertNotNull(result);
        Assertions.assertEquals(expectednames, result);
    }
}
```

So we are mock all the services we use in controller, then inject to controller itself. Then inside the test method we mock `repo.findAll()` to return `expectedNames` so if the controller find that function it will return what mock says to return.

After we call the function, we have to make it sure that the result is according to what we expected.

Comment: This does succeed in injecting my mocks into my controller, but I don't get a chance to initialize my mocks before they are injected, so the controller's constructor does not get to see mock data.

Answer (score 1):

There is little value in a "unit test" for a `@Controller` implementation. If you use `@WebMvcTest`, then you can use `@MockBean`:

```
@WebMvcTest
class MyControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @MockBean
  private MyRepository repository;

  @Test
  void testSomething() {
    mockMvc.perform( ... );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would I not want to unit test my controllers? I have non-trivial businesses logic in them. In traditional MVC models, most of the logic should be in the controller layer.

Comment: Because controllers usually have a lot of annotations where you also want to test those. This is easiest using `@WebMvcTest`. Normally controllers should _not_ have business logic in them. They should only deal with the HTTP conversion. I place business logic in the services layer.